# How to search/filter/type-match through dynamically build multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to search/filter a multidimensional array which varies in the number of dimensions (because it represents a file tree) by its `name` value with ES6 filter method but struggling to also return the nested objects.

What the array looks like:

```
const fileHierarchy = [
  {
    name: 'folder1',
    children: [
        { name: 'file1.txt' },
        { name: 'file2.txt' },
        {
            name: 'child folder1',
            children: [
                {
                    name: 'child folder2',
                    children: [
                        { name: 'file3.txt' },
                        { name: 'file4.txt' }
                    ]
                },
                { name: 'file5.txt' },
                { name: 'file6.txt' },
                {
                    name: 'child folder3',
                    children: [
                        { name: 'file7.txt' },
                        { name: 'file8.txt' }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
  },
  {name: 'folder2'}
]
```

This is what I have already tried (and what my array/object looks like):

```
let currentFileHierarchy;
let searchString = 'file5';

currentFileHierarchy = fileHierarchy.filter(function (item) {
    return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.toLowerCase()) >= 0 
});
```

The result of `currentFileHierarchy` is only one dimensional (only `folder1` and `folder2` is searchable) but it should also include all the nested objects which match the search string.

If there is a way to manage that is it also possible to maintain the array structure? Or do I need to flatten it first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, flatten out the array to get the list of names:

```
function flatten(names, arr) {
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    names.push(item.name);
    if (item.children) {
      flatten(names, item.children);
    }
  });
  return names;
}

var results = [];
flatten(results, fileHierarchy);

// 'results' has all the names now
```

Use the `results` array to filter upon.

Comment: I have Lodash and tried the linked approach but after flattening the given array with `const result = _.flatMap(fileHierarchy, ({ name, children }) =>
                  _.map(children, children => ({ name, ...children }))
                );` I get an odd result of only 3 array objects.

Comment: wait, let me check

Comment: @MangoD check my answer now.

Comment: @MangoD did you check?

Comment: Thank you! Looking quite good now. The only thing which is left is that I need to maintain at least the structure of the object. E.g. `{name: 'file1.txt'}`. Because there will probably more keys added `{name: 'file1.txt', format: 'txt'}`.

Comment: change to `push(item)` instead of `push(item.name)`

Comment: If I push the whole item with `push(item)` it will also add the children and I don't have a flat array anymore. I used `push({'name': item.name, 'format': item.format})` now. Thanks!

Comment: @MangoD happy to help! :)